# Need help to better understand RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I am learning RMI and I have done something like:

`Interface`

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface IRemote extends Remote {
    public void say() throws RemoteException;
}
```

`Server`

```
 import java.rmi.*;
 import java.rmi.server.*;

 public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IRemote{

     public Server() throws RemoteException{}

        public void say() throws RemoteException{
            System.out.println("I am saying Hello World...");
        } 

        public static void main (String[] argv) {
           try {
                          Naming.rebind ("myserver", new Server());
                          System.out.println ("Server is ready.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println ("Hello Server failed: " + e);
                  }
         }
     }
```

`Client`

```
  import java.rmi.*;

   class Client{
      public static void main(String args[]){
            try{
                  IRemote obj = (IRemote) Naming.lookup ("rmi://MYPCNAME/myserver");
                        obj.say();
                }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception : "+e);
            }
       }
 }
```

And to run, I am first starting RMI registry.

`start rmiregistry` then `java Server` and then `java Client`

This thing is working fine when I am having all these three things in same package. But that is not what RMI is all about. I should be able to put Client on some other machine or other location and then call Server methods from there.

But when I do change package of Client.java and I try to compile it, I get the error:

`Client.java:6: error: cannot find symbol`
`IRemote obj = (IRemote) Naming.lookup ("rmi://MYPCNAME/myserver");`
`symbol:   class IRemote`
`location: class Client`

It says it can't find IRemote, which is present in the package of Server. I want to know, how can I make this thing working properly? Both Client and Server on different packages or machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the lack of an `import` statement.

When `Client` was in the same package as `IRemote`, you could refer to it without needing to import it.  As soon as you moved the interface, your `Client` class no longer knew how to find it.

Comment: Well, I know that very well...! but what when we do move our Client program to some other machine and Server on some other machine? Then how do you think you are going to import interface? (What RMI is all about)

Comment: Package your interfaces in a single JAR, then compile your client and server against that JAR.

Comment: Do you want to say, we do need interface on both sides ? Client side as well as Server side?

Comment: No, you need the interface on _both_ sides.

Comment: That's okay ! :) Are you sure about this thing? That in standard Java RMI working way, the interface should be available on both sides? Any references?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17170/discussion-between-david-grant-and-gps)